# How get azure storage table timestamp as string?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I can get storage table rows using this PowerShell command:

```
$temp_table_name = "MY_TABLE_NAME"
$saContext = (Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Name $storageAccount).Context
$temp_table = Get-AzureStorageTable -Name $temp_table_name -Context $saContext
$result = Get-AzureStorageTableRowAll -table $temp_table
```

I have two Timestamp in my table, one is for azure table itself with name `Timestamp` and another one is for Metrics (stored automatically) with name `TIMESTAMP`. then the result of `$result[0]` is like bellow:

```
Average      : 3228132966.4
Count        : 240
CounterName  : \Memory\AvailableMemory
DeploymentId : 2c90752b-100f-4640-a056-e2b894bf5bd5
Host         : cpuusagetest
Last         : 3230662656
Maximum      : 3231711232
Minimum      : 3225419776
TIMESTAMP    : 10/16/2017 10:00:00 PM
Total        : 774751911936
PartitionKey : *************
RowKey       : ***************__:005CMemory:005CAvailableMemory
Etag         : W/"datetime'2017-10-16T23%3A00%3A05.5000867Z'"
```

I don't know why there is just `TIMESTAMP` and another one is `Etag`! in the result. anyway I can get Timestamp using this command:

```
$result[0].Timestamp
```

it will return always an string like **`10/16/2017 23:00:00`**, but in table's row it's stored something like **`2017-10-16T23:30:00.000`**. I need to get exactly the format that it's stored in the storage table.

I tried to change the format using a command like this:

```
[String]$result[0].Timestamp
or
$result[$j].Timestamp.toString("s")
```

but the result is same.

Please note When I am using `$result[$j].Timestamp.GetType().FullName` result is `System.DateTime`, then the **type** of Timestamp property in my table is **`DateTime`** and I can't (and don't want) to change it.

[image: it's a screenshot of my Azure Storage Explorer that is showing that I have Minute & Second & milliseconds in my Timestamp]
Above is a screenshot of my Azure Storage Explorer that is showing that I have Minute & Second & milliseconds in my Timestamp

but when I am using this command:

```
$result[$j].Timestamp.toString("s")
```

result is without minuets and seconds...
I even test these commands too:

```
"{0:MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss}" -f $result[$j].Timestamp
```

but the result is something like `10/16/2017 10:00:00`

Can you please guide me?

Answer (score 1):

Provided any object of type DateTime d, the command d.ToString("s") will give back the date object in the format 2017-10-16T23:30:00.000

If you have a string and need to convert it to a DateTime, the following will perform a conversion between date strings of different formats:

```
[DateTime]::Parse("10/16/2017 23:00:00").ToString("s")
```

With the above evaluating to "2017-10-16T23:30:00.000"

Comment: yes, it's changing the format, but I will lose minuets, seconds and milliseconds, because when I am getting information from storage table, it will change the format and it will remove these things! and when I Parse it to String, it will be removed... :(

Comment: Not sure why you think it's going to remove the minutes and seconds - if the internal storage type is a `DateTime`, then a `ToString("s")` will return that rows timestamp in the "same format that it's stored". (as an aside - if `$result[0].TIMESTAMP` is already a `DateTime`, no need to parse - just `ToString()` it)  That said, perhaps you need to let us know why you need to convert it to a string, and what you're doing with it - there may be an alternative solution to the problem you're trying to solve

Comment: @BrendanGreen I have added some more information. I need this timestamp because it's system's metrics that stored into the Azure Storage Table automatically, and there is several type of metrics for a same timestamp (like CPU, Memory, Network & etc.) and I need to merge all the separated metric rows for the same timestamp, to one row and store it into another table.